# Is it possible to have a cronjob/pod inside a namespaced kubernetes (AKS) cluster which deletes "Completed" pods without using Kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-cronjob

**Current state:** From local command line, after authenticating to the cluster and setting the right context, I am using Kubectl to get list of "Completed" pods and then deleting them using a simple one liner. This works, but we want to automate it.

These are pods NOT jobs which are in "Completed" state. I am aware of ttl settings for jobs and but I cannot find similar settings for Pods.

**Future state:** We want to be able to deploy a pod/cronjob inside a namespace which will just look for "Completed" pods and delete them, without using Kubectl. My understanding is that this would be a security risk if we allow a Pod to have Kubectl access. Correct me if I am wrong. That being said, how could we do it if there is a way?

Answer (score 1):

> We want to be able to deploy a pod/cronjob inside a namespace which will just look for "Completed" pods and delete them, without using Kubectl.

This should work perfectly fine. Just make sure that the ServiceAccount has RBAC permissions to delete those pods.

> My understanding is that this would be a security risk if we allow a Pod to have Kubectl access. Correct me if I am wrong.

This should be fine. But you should practice *least privilege* and configure the RBAC permissions to only allow just this operation, e.g. only delete Pods, and only within the same namespace.

> That being said, how could we do it if there is a way?

This should be possible with an image containing `kubectl` and proper RBAC permissions for the ServiceAccount.

Comment: ...or using your choice of [Kubernetes client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#officially-supported-client-libraries), if you'd rather use a higher-level language than `kubectl`.  But the same comments about service accounts and RBAC still apply.